# Why is Shiva bhakti termed as the religion of Monsters in the Vamana purana?

Tags: shiva, puranas, worship, bhakti, shaivism

Vaman Purāna 11.15-16,26 says this

[image]

Does this mean if I devote myself to Shiva with the exclusion of all other devatas, It would make me a demon?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean if I devote myself to Shiva with the exclusion of all other devatas, It would make me a demon?

**This section of the Purana is not saying that worshippers of Shiva are demons.**

This section of the purana is giving the dharmas of various classes of beings like Devas, Gandharvas, Daityas, Humans, Rakshasas, Siddhas, Vidyadharas etc. Worship of Shiva is included in the dharma of Rakshasas. But, it is also included in the dharma of humans (see below).

Coming to the specific question, [dharma of humans is given here in 11.23-24](https://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/vamp__u.htm)

> svādhyāyaṃ brahmacaryaṃ ca dānaṃ yajanameva
> ca
> akārpaṇyamanāyāsaṃ dayāhiṃsā kṣamā damaḥ

> jitendriyatvaṃ śaucaṃ ca māṅgalyaṃ bhaktiracyute /
> **śaṅkare** bhāskare devyāṃ **dharmo 'yaṃ mānavaḥ** smṛtaḥ

[Translation here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313087/page/n109/mode/1up)

> Recitation of the vedas, continence, charity, worship, benevolence, ease, compassion, non-violence, forgiveness, control of senses, self-restraint, purity and auspiciousness and **devotion to Shankara**, Surya and Bhavani **are indicated as religion of man.**

These are all very positive qualities, combined with the worship of Shiva. There is **no** denigration of worship of Shiva here.